# In FLASK, how to create a HTML button which when pressed gives results (output of a python file) on the same page without going to another route?

Tags: python, html, flask

Here is my directory setup:

```
/output
  /text_file.txt
/templates
  /index.html
app.py
read.py
```

Here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div>
        </div>
        <button><a href="/abc"> Read</a></button>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, redirect, request

import fitz

from read import read_txt


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
  return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/abc')
def link():
  return read_txt("text_file.txt")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5000, debug = True)
```

and this is my read.py:

```
import os

def read_txt(file):
    doc = os.getcwd()+"\\output\\"+file
    with open(doc,"r") as f:
        text = f.read()

        return text
```

**Question:** I am reading a txt file in python. I want to make an html page with a button READ which when clicked will show me the content of txt file on the same page(same route path: http://127.0.0.1:5000/ ), inside that defined div component.

But for now, when I click on button, output is showing in another route (http://127.0.0.1:5000/abc).

I am really struggling with this. I read somewhere that we can use jinja template but I am not sure how to do this.

I am sorry if it is a very basic question but I am a begineer and unable to figure it out.

Thank you.

Comment: this is where js magic comes take place

Comment: Can you please provide some help with code? I am not sure how to do this with JavaScript also. And one more thing, JS not working with my flask. I provided an external JS for some different purpose in static folder and used appropriate link in html "<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='map.js') }}"></script>". This didn't work.